# Unable to add new datastreams to some specific objects in Fedora repository (Fedora commons)

Tags: fedora-commons

I need help in resolving this issue. I am unable to add new datastreams to a few specific objects in the Fedora repository but have no clue what's really wrong about this objects. Here is the error trace I get:

HTTP code=500, Reason=Internal Server Error, body=javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: org.fcrepo.server.errors.ObjectNotFoundException: Error creating replication job: The requested object doesn't exist in the registry.

**Traceback (most recent call last):**
File "/opt/2.0/flx/pylons/flx/compress_upload_images.py", line 159, in run

> obj.addDataStream(cDSName, fc.getDSXml(r.type.name), label=label, mimeType=h.safe_decode('%s' % mimeType), controlGroup=controlGroup, logMessage=h.safe_decode('Storing compressed %s' % r.type.name))

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/fcrepo/object.py", line 64, in addDataStream

> self.client.addDatastream(self.pid, dsid, body, **params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/fcrepo/client.py", line 119, in addDatastream

> response = request.submit(body, **params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/fcrepo/wadl.py", line 81, in submit

> method=self.method.name)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/fcrepo/connection.py", line 80, in open

> return check_response_status(self.conn.getresponse())

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/fcrepo/connection.py", line 107, in check_response_status

> **raise ex
>   FedoraConnectionException: HTTP code=500, Reason=Internal Server Error, body=javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: org.fcrepo.server.errors.ObjectNotFoundException: Error creating replication job: The requested object doesn't exist in the registry.**

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to fix this issue. The problem was basically the database used by the Fedora Commons was inconsistent and for the image objects that I was facing the issue, entries were not present in the db. The inconsistency had happened due to some migration that happened and some rows were missed. We had to copy the missing data from the old database to the new one and it worked this time!